# Selenium Grid necessary with Appium using real devices?

Tags: java, android, appium, selenium-grid

One of the things that my team has been talking about is hooking up our appium tests (that are ran through physical devices) to the grid. I dont see what this could accomplish.. Due to the fact that you can not run more than one test at a time per appium server (I may be wrong.. I have tried making them not run parallel, and instead one at a time but it did not work for me). We have several test classes, say 10 in a suite, so does that mean I need 10 devices?

I guess my main concern is that I am thinking about this all wrong.. Anyone who has experience with syncing up their appium tests to their grid, either physical or emulated devices, please let me know how it works and what can be accomplished. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience and understanding the Selenium Grid is very helpful because following:

1. You do not need to worry where the device is connected;
2. You can easily see current status of your connected devices via the UI;
3. You can run tests in parallel for several devices with different OS.